# Simulation model problem

Tags: ltspice, simulation, model

Recently I have downloaded a model from Toshiba's web site and tried to create a simple circuit like in the image below.

[image: Simulated circuit]

The signal on the "V(n002)" point wasn't like I expect.  After that, I found out that there is another model file which comes with LTSpice. I tried that also and it works as I expected. Both simulation outputs can be seen in the images.

I am not able to do a comparison between both models , because the one from LTSpice is encrpted so there is no way to inspect the model.

At this point, I just would like to ask what might be the problem with the model which comes directly from Toshiba.

Any help is appreciated

---

**LTSpice model local path:**
Program Files\LTC\LTspiceXVII\lib\sub\Contrib\Toshiba\pmos\SSM3J56MFV.lib

[Toshiba model web link:](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=15091&prodName=SSM3J56MFV&displang=en)

---

[image: Toshiba model output]
[image: LTSpice model output]

Comment: LTSpice doesn't normally encrypt models as far as I know --> *the one from LTSpice is encrpted*

Comment: ...Contrib\Toshiba\pmos\SSM3J56MFV.lib this model file seems enrypted in my computer. When I open it in a file editor there is nothing readable.

Comment: You have the one from Toshiba's website connected incorrectly.  SPICE pin order for MOSFETs is D G S.  You have it connected as G S D.  In other words, pin 1 on your symbol should be D, pin 2 should be G, and pin 3 should be S.  Fix that.

Comment: Thank you Ste. I didn't know that. It works properly now.

Comment: Here's a reference so you can avoid using that generic box symbol with subcircuit MOSFETs.  https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-using-an-intrinsic-symbol-for-a-third-party-model.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the one from Toshiba's website connected incorrectly. SPICE pin ordering for MOSFETs is `D G S`. You have it connected as `G S D`. In other words, pin 1 on your symbol should be `D`, pin 2 should be `G`, and pin 3 should be `S`.  When in doubt of what the pin order for a particular symbol is, you can always CTRL+rightclick it and click the "Open Symbol" button.  Then rightclick each pin to see its "Netlist Order"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's a reference so you can avoid using that generic box symbol with subcircuit MOSFETs:
https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-using-an-intrinsic-symbol-for-a-third-party-model.html